# Dynamically create view

Tags: ember.js

I'm generating a list of views that the client should cycle through on the server.   The server returns a list of something like 'App.AView', 'App.BView', 'App.CView", ..., etc. that refer to views and templates on the client.

I'd like to dynamically create these views, swap out the previous view, and include the new view.   My first though was to compile a handlebars template with this dynamic view name, ala:

```
App.QuestionView = Em.View.extend({
    template: function() {
         return Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view " + this.get("view_name') + "}}");
    }
});
```

Which works, but seems ugly - is there a way to create a view with a string of the view name in Ember.JS and replace an existing view in a parent view with that view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at Ember.ContainerView, which will let you programmatically manage a set of child views. Container View's documentation is excellent, check out: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html

Since it sounds like you only ever want one view displayed at a time you can focus on the `currentView` property, which will automatically maintain your `childViews` array for displaying a single view.

Also here is an example: http://www.emberplay.com/#/workspace/2792969430